# Exception : could not prepare statement

Tags: mysql, excel, hibernate

> This is the Controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addToView", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    public Response addToView(@RequestBody ClassA classA){
        return  service1.addToview(classA);
    }
```

This is the DAO class

```
 public Response addToview(ClassA classA){                   
            try{
                s=sf.openSession();
                tx=s.beginTransaction();
                String q="INSERT INTO abc(rollNo,name,english) VALUES("+classA.getRollNo()+","+classA.getName()+","+classA.getEnglish()+")";
                System.out.println(q);
                Query query=s.createSQLQuery(q);
                query.executeUpdate();
                response.setStatus(200);
                response.setMessage("succesfull");
                tx.commit();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
                response.setStatus(500);
                response.setMessage("unsuccesfull");
                tx.rollback();
            } finally {
                s.close();
            }
            return response;
        }
```

> Here the query is getting executed in sql console but when i am trying
>   implement it in the code it is not working it is giving error saying
>   could not prepare statement

Comment: Can you please post entire stack trace, not just the (paraphrased) error message?

Comment: 05:59:58#+00#ERROR#com.excel.studentDAO.StudentDAO##anonymous#https-jsse-nio-8041-exec-24#na#p2001005741trial#generateaexcel#web#p2001005741trial#na#na#na#na#Exception : could not prepare statement